# jqplot replot not working for bar chart

Tags: javascript, yii, jqplot

I am taking graph plot points from database and replotting graph after every 10 seconds so that any change in database is reflected on graph. But in my case this is not working and graph changes only when I reload the page. Following is my code

```
 <?php
   $z_data = json_encode($this->testData('123'));
  ?>
```

javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    var s2 = $z_data;
    var plot5 = $.jqplot('big', [s2], {
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            }
        },
        highlighter: { show: false }
    });
    $('a[href="#dash4"]').on('shown', function(g) {
        plot5.replot();
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        var s4 = [];
        var toi = $z_data
        for (var k=0; k<11; k++){ 
            s4.push([k, toi[k]]);
        }


        $('#big').unbind();
        plot5.destroy();
        plot5.series[0].data = s4;
        plot5.resetAxesScale();
        plot5.replot(true);
        }, 
        10000
    );

    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = false;

});
```

Where I am making mistake? Also database gets updated every 5 seconds so the change should be reflected on graph since I updating it every 10 seconds.

Comment: Declarations of s2 and s4 are different. Try to specify s2 as s4 as it works for this last one

Comment: No this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/KMd49/1/)

In the example i have assumed dummy data to prove the code concept.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
    var s2 = [1,2,4,5,7,23,4,40,7,3,8];
    var plot5 = $.jqplot('big', [s2], {
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            }
        },
        highlighter: { show: false }
    });
    $('a[href="#dash4"]').on('shown', function(g) {
        plot5.replot();
    });

    setInterval(function () {
        var s4 = [];
        s2.shift();
        var toi = s2;
        toi.push(Math.round(Math.random()*10));
        for (var k=0; k<11; k++){ 
            s4.push([k+1, toi[k]]);
        }

        plot5.destroy();
        plot5.series[0].data = s4;
        plot5.replot(true);
        }, 
        10000
    );

});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to define the plot5 as a global Variable.

Comment: Why is that? It is not referenced outside of the ready callback function scope.

Comment: plot5 is in the function.so when you are accessing variable it will show undefined.

Comment: Yes, if you try to access it outside of the ready function. It doesn't look like OP is trying to do this, though.